# Always required to use "sudo" in the terminal

Tags: mac, administrator, sudo

Recently I've noticed that every time I try to use a command like "mkdir", I get "permission denied" when used without "sudo". I guess that's because I am not connected as an admin, only as far as I am concerned (and the System Preferences "Accounts" window) I am.

This happens only after certain time that I do not use the computer.

Any idea why this could happen?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The problem happens only with a specific folder, which is used by MAMP PRO. MAMP has its own settings page for the permissions, but when I change owner control to admin, PHP uploads doesn't work. When I change it to _www, everything related to this folder requires authentication.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Well I described a problem and looked for a solution, anyway edited so it's clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `sudo`, you have the privileges of your own user account. If you do use `sudo`, you have root privileges.

Whether you can do a `mkdir` without `sudo` depends on the ownership and permissions of the current directory. If you're in a directory that you own (such as your home directory), you should be able to `mkdir` without any problem.

Note that `sudo mkdir` has effects other than increasing your privilege level. It runs the `mkdir` command under the `root` account -- which means that the newly created directory will be owned by `root`, not by you.  If you've been habitually using `sudo mkdir`, you'll have created directories that you don' have permission to modify from your own user account.

Run `ls -ld DIRNAME` to see the ownership and permissions of any directory.

It rarely makes sense to have root-owned files or directories anywhere under your own home directory (`~`, `$HOME`). If you've accidentally created such files or directories, you can use

```
sudo chmod $USER ...
```

to change their ownership back to your own account.

And don't use `sudo` unless you really need to.

Comment: I am the administrator, the thing is that I am required to input a password to verify each action I do, not only in the terminal - Also when I move files and rename. This happens only after a certain time (1-2 hours) that I don't use the computer.

Comment: I think being the "adminstrator" just means you're *able* to use `sudo`. When you run `sudo ...` and enter your password, it remembers it for 15 minutes (unless it's configured differently). Are these files you're manipulating under your home directory or elsewhere?

Comment: They're under my home directory.

Comment: @AdamGold: Normally, you should never need to use `sudo` to manipulate files under your home directory; they should all be owned by your user account. If they're owned by `root`, it's probably because you've used `sudo` unnecessarily.

Comment: Okay, I will delete the folder I've created with sudo and will manually create it. How do I fix the problem with the permissions?

Comment: @AdamGold: You can use `sudo chown $USER ...`.  `man chown` for details. And again, don't use `sudo` unless you really need to -- and for anything under your home directory, you shouldn't need to. (You may need to use it a bit to clean up your current mess.)

Comment: Okay, thanks. But without sudo I can't do nothing in the terminal after I don't use the computer for a certain time, how can I fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4378/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-adamgold)